# Apply an AppleScript to a Specific Email Message in Mail

Tags: email, applescript

I have an AppleScript I want to apply to individual emails (to archive them as PDFs with a particular file name), ut can't work out how to apply it to specific emails.

I can't set up a mail rule to run the script as it is just my judgment as to whether I want to archive one out of Mail or not. Have tried setting it up as a Service, but there is no Services menu on right clicking an email in Mail.

Any suggestions?!

Rich

Answer (score 0):

How are you planning on specifying which individual emails? If by selecting them manually, you can “get selection”. Here’s a simple script that will get the subject and message Id of each selected message.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set mySelection to get selection
    set eMails to {}
    repeat with selectedMessage in mySelection
        set messageId to selectedMessage's message id as string
        set eMail to selectedMessage's subject & ": " & messageId
        tell me to set end of eMails to eMail
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\n\n"
    set the clipboard to (eMails as string)
end tell
```

Save it in ~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Mail/ and it will show up in your Scripts menu. You may have to go to AppleScript Editor’s settings to “Show Script menu in menu bar” to make the Scripts menu show up.

(Note: when you compile this script, the \n\n will turn into new lines.)